# Google Chrome Sync Settings

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization, settings

Google Chrome Sync Settings shows 'Sync is disabled by your administrator.'
I'm using my company's laptop and I'd like to sync my content to my Google Account with which I have already logged into Google Chrome.
Not able to turn Sync ON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to talk to your company's IT department, as they have [deliberately disabled Chrome Sync](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6309115?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, so far it is possible to use the browser [Iron Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/iron_portable), that can sync with Chrome (it is a Chrome-like browser), and apparently ignores these user policy settings, as it is able to sync all data correctly.